# How can I implement highlighting cells in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, jointjs

I've implemented highlighting selected cells the way jointjs suggests with the highlight() method, which surrounds the cell with a 2 pixel red border. This works perfectly with Chrome but I need the outline to work in IE. I looked through joint.css and they noted that outline does not work in IE so what they've done instead is change the opacity when a cell is highlighted. This is not nearly as convenient for the user since a cell looks disabled when selected.

How can I implement highlighting so that a cell is surrounded by an outline much in the same way it occurs in Chrome? Any ideas/suggestions would be much appreciated.

```js
var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

var width = 400;
var height = 400;
var gridSize = 1;

var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    el: $('#paper'),
    width: width,
    height: height,
    model: graph,
    gridSize: gridSize
});

paper.on('cell:pointerdown', function(cellView, evt, x, y){
      cellView.highlight();//highlight clicked element
});

var actor = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
    position: {x:100, y:30},
    attrs: {text: {text: 'drag me'}},
    size: { height: 92.7051, width: 150}
});

graph.addCell(actor);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jointjs.com/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jointjs.com/css/joint.css" />        
<script src="http://jointjs.com/js/joint.js"></script>

<div id="paper"/>
```

Comment: Can you post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 1):

**JointJS v0.9.7 and lower**

The `joint.dia.Paper` triggers `cell:highlight` and `cell:unhighlight` whenever a cell is highlighted resp. unhighlighted. It is possible to unbind the default highlighting

```
paper.off('cell:highlight cell:unhighlight');
```

and bind a custom one. For instance:

```
// A rectangular highlighter element
var highlighter = V('rect', {
    'stroke': '#ff7e5d',
    'stroke-width': '6px',
    'fill': 'transparent',
    'pointer-events': 'none'
});

paper.on({
    'cell:highlight': function(cellView, el, opt) {
        // measure the element meant to be highlighted
        var bbox = V(el).bbox(false, paper.viewport);
        // set `x`, `y`, `width` and `hight` onto the highlighter element
        highlighter.attr(bbox);
        // add the highlighter to the DOM
        V(paper.viewport).append(highlighter);
     },

     'cell:unhighlight': function(cellView, el, opt) {
         // remove the highlighter from the DOM
         highlighter.remove();
     }
});
```

Please see the following JSFiddle or check out the demos on the JointJS web that also demonstrate the highlighting.

- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kumilingus/6d4tsfc4/)
- [DEVS demo](http://jointjs.com/demos/devs)
- [ERD demo](http://jointjs.com/demos/erd)

**JointJS v0.9.9 and higher**

The cellView highlighting has been refactored. The CSS `outline` property is not used anymore. There is an SVGPath Element, which mimics the shape boundary, appended directly to the cellView instead. For more info please see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361870/cellview-highlight-breaking-change/38401539#38401539).

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post but someone may find it helpful. No IE on my machine to test it but here is one way of implementing your own highlighter.

```js
var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

var width = 400;
var height = 400;
var gridSize = 1;

var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    el: $('#paper'),
    width: width,
    height: height,
    model: graph,
    gridSize: gridSize
});

paper.on('cell:pointerdown', function(cellView, evt, x, y){
      //cellView.highlight();//highlight clicked element
      myHighlight(cellView.model.id);
});

var actor = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
    position: {x:100, y:30},
    attrs: {text: {text: 'drag me'}},
    size: { height: 92.7051, width: 150}
});

var myHighlight = function(cellId) {
    var cell = graph.getCell(cellId);
    cell.attr({
        rect: {
            stroke: 'red'
        }
    });
};

graph.addCell(actor);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jointjs.com/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jointjs.com/css/joint.css" />        
<script src="http://jointjs.com/js/joint.js"></script>

<div id="paper"/>
```