# CellView.highlight() breaking change?

Tags: javascript, jointjs

My application uses Jointjs.

I recently upgraded from Jointjs v0.9.7 to v0.9.10 and since I did that cell highlighting does not seem to work. I simplified everything down to a test app and I can see that the `highlight()` function is called but the `highlighted` class is not set.

I put a simplified test page into [a gist](https://gist.github.com/mike-goodwin/3021dbf10b0965b5864fd72bfcce9bb4) and [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t10ku9kj/2/). It is also reproduced below in case it helps.

Has there been a breaking change? How is highlighting supposed to work in v0.9.10?

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jointjs/0.9.10/joint.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jointjs/0.9.10/joint.core.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="paper" />

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jointjs/0.9.10/joint.js"></script>
    <script>
        //there is a problem with jointjs in the latest version of Chrome. This fixes it
        SVGElement.prototype.getTransformToElement =
            SVGElement.prototype.getTransformToElement || function (toElement) {
                return toElement.getScreenCTM().inverse().multiply(this.getScreenCTM());
            };

        var highlighted = false;

        var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;
        var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
            el: $('#paper'),
            width: 400,
            height: 400,
            model: graph,
            gridSize: 1,
            interactive: false
        });

        paper.on('cell:pointerclick', function (cellView) {

            if (highlighted) {
                cellView.unhighlight();
            } else {
                cellView.highlight();
            }

            highlighted = !highlighted
        });

        var element = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
            position: { x: 100, y: 30 },
            attrs: { text: { text: 'my shape' } },
            size: { height: 92.7051, width: 150 }
        });

        graph.addCell(element);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default highlighter has changed in JointJS v0.9.10. When you highlight an element - an SVGPathElement with the `joint-highlight-stroke` class name that mimics the element shape is appended directly to the ElementView. This solves differences across the browsers with CSS property `outline` mostly unsupported for SVG Elements.

Available `highlighters` resides in the `joint.highlighters` namespace (`stroke` *default*, `opacity`, `addClass` *for backwards compatibility*).

In order to restore the original behaviour, please use the following.

```
// a highlighter definition
var myHighlighter = {
    name: 'addClass',
    options: {
        className: 'highlighted'
    }
}

// add `myHighlighter` to an `el` (`null` for the entire cellView) DOM element.
cellView.highlight(el, myHighlighter);
// remove `myHighlighter` from an `el` DOM element.
cellView.unhighlight(el, myHighlighter);
```

Note that the new changes allow highlighting cellViews with multiple highlighters.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kumilingus/jn2594mk/)

Sorry for inconveniences. The actual documentation for highlighters will appear in the JointJS repository ASAP.